# What is the different between Cloud storage and cloud computing?

Tags: cloud

Instead of "Cloud storage" people often say "Cloud". Is dropbox only a Cloud storage or a cloud computing? Because dropbox can not only storage documents, but also edit documents.

Answer (score 0):

The proper and general term is "Cloud Computing" and most of the people refer to it as the "Cloud". Cloud Computing offers Compute, Storage, Database and Network services. It is basically a remote virtual pool of resources. The clue here is that you can access those resources on-demand and don't have to pay anything up-front.

Dropbox is only a Cloud Storage service. It is hosted in the Cloud, so that you, me or anyone else can access data from anywhere. Basically as I said before, Cloud Storage is only one part or service of Cloud Computing.

Hope that helps.

All best,
Murat

Comment: Teşekkürler murat. Yani cloud storage clod computing in bir parçasımi? O zaman dropbox cloud computing in bir parçası mı?

Comment: Aynen evet. @dernecati

Answer (score 0):

**Cloud Storage**

Cloud storage is simply storing data and files, and performing backups to an external location offsite. The main benefit of this solution is it ensures a company’s data is kept secure and readily available in case onsite data is lost, or there is some form of unexpected disaster, like a fire which destroys the business. Plus, data is stored on a virtual server, not the employees’ actual devices.

**Cloud Computing**

Cloud computing is running applications through a virtual desktop over a secure internet connection. There are numerous benefits companies gain with this solution, including:

-No special hardware requirements.
-The ability to access apps and data from just about anywhere on just about any device.
-Rolling out upgrades, updates, and patches is fast, simple, and easy since it only needs
to be performed on the virtual server, not on every single employee computer and/or
device.

Combining cloud storage with cloud computing provides companies the benefits of both services.